# Looking for a plural noun related to ‘fulcrum’ or ‘pivot’ that denotes multiple things as crucial to success

Tags: single-word-requests

The title says it all. I will include an example sentence to contextualise how I want to use this word:

> Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are the _____ to human prosperity—not selfishness.

Of course I can reframe the sentence and just simply say “are crucial to” or “are pivotal to”, but I really want a plural noun that is similar to fulcrum to designate more than one thing as being pivotal to give the sentence extra “punch”.

I checked and found that ‘fulcra’ is the plural noun of fulcrum, but it just sounds a little awkward for my liking and I could not find sufficient examples of it used in sentences.

Comment: This is not a matter of words; this is a matter of metaphors. If you use a teeter-totter/balance scale metaphor, there can only be two weights and one fulcrum. A balance with two fulcrums is not a balance. You could use a door metaphor and call them the _keys_ to success. Or you could say they're the basic ingredients and use a food metaphor. Just matching words by perceived meaning leads to mixed metaphors.

Comment: You could also use a building metaphor, *pillars*, which is often used with prosperity: *Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are the pillars of human prosperity—not selfishness.*

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. The plural of [*fulcrum*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulcrum) is also **fulcrums**. In fact, Merriam-Webster lists it in the first position, so it's likely more common.

Comment: Accepting @John's point - "keys" seems the obvious metaphor, or you could say they were the ***criteria*** "to human prosperity". Or you could say they were ***critical*** to "human prosperity".

Comment: @JohnLawler that'd make a great answer

Comment: as @JohnLawler explained, both fulcrum and pivot are totally incorrect here.

Comment: "are pivotal to" would be completely wrong, you can't have more than one.

Comment: Saloon door hinges have two pivots. Both of them *are pivotal to* the door being able to open 180 degrees. ("adjective: *pivotal* : of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else."). *fulcra* adds some "punch" without being a cliche; *pivotal* is the word normally used here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[**Cornerstone**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cornerstone)

> something that is essential, indispensable, or basic

(source: Dictionary.com)

The sentence would become:

> Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are the cornerstones *of* human prosperity—not selfishness

Comment: I think this is the one! I always struggle to distinguish it from keystone.

Comment: @R.Cunliffe - keystones are fairly vital, too.

Comment: It may sound a bit odd that there are only three cornerstones rather than four, though.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Keystones are exactly as vital as all the other stones.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - All rectangular buildings have four *corner* (space) *stones*. What would weird is if it had four *cornerstones* "carved with the date and laid with appropriate ceremonies." – [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cornerstone) . There's only *up to* one keystone per arch, and one cornerstone per building. Using either to metaphorically refer to more than one thing is already pushing it.

Comment: @Mazura: Every monarchy can only have one king too but that doesn't mean that "Robert Plant and Pete Townshend are the kings of rock" is somehow "pushing it". Figurative usage gets more leeway and does not need to completely conform to the origin of its reference.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni What's odd (other than the number itself :-)) about [three cornerstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatiron_Building) or even [five cornerstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pentagon)?

Comment: One cornerstone per building, but multiple buildings per town == multiple cornerstones. (I.e. the metaphor for "human prosperity" in the example would become town, not building. Seems Ok.)

Comment: @Flater Narnia had two kings and two queens.

Answer (score 36):

I think a very simple word works best here, namely *keys*:

> 2 b : an instrumental or deciding factor
>   // the *key* to her success

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/key))

It will be understood by virtually everybody, unlike fulcrum which I actually had to look up...

Answer (score 27):

**pillars**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143897?rskey=YOUeGt&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> A fact or principle which is a main support or basis of something.

As in:

> 1920   *F. S. Fitzgerald* This Side of Paradise    There had been a
>   time when his own Celtic traits were pillars of his personal
>   philosophy.

... the **pillars** to human prosperity

A **pillar** can be someone or thing that is considered a foundational or supportive. Someone indispensable to your company might be considered a pillar to the organization, a loved one a/the **pillar** of your life.

Comment: The thing I like with "pillars" is that you cant remove too many of them without "it" collapsing.

Answer (score 17):

**Linchpins** also comes to mind. From [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linchpin)

> One that serves to hold together parts or elements that exist or function as a unit.

Answer (score 12):

**Foundations** would work (and is almost a synonym of *cornerstones*). "Foundations of human prosperity" results in a few literal google hits.

(If you allowed verbs I would actually opt for *hinges* which preserves your mental image of "pivoting": Human prosperity **hinges on** cooperation, reciprocity and trust. A nice side benefit is that you can have multiple hinges, as opposed to only a single fulcrum ;-).)

---

<sub>Because this answer was deemed too short by a reviewer I'll mention the obvious reasons to give this answer: Like *cornerstone,* *foundation* denotes a base on which another thing (here: human prosperity) rests and without which it cannot be established, which makes it a good term for a *sine qua non,* which is how I understand the question. The google hits are a good enough reference for me — they show that the literal word combination is indeed used, at least occasionally.</sub>

Comment: Or in adjective form: "Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are foundational to human prosperity—not selfishness."

Comment: @GEdgar I'd also prefer adjectives, but the OP explicitly wants to use nouns.

Answer (score 5):

Consider **basis**

> Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are the **basis** of human
>   prosperity—not selfishness.

EDIT: Per comments below, **bases** is truly the correct term... but basis is arguably usable because the three (cooperation, reciprocity, trust) can be considered together as one.

Comment: Someone will probably point out that the plural is 'bases'. Like you, I'd use 'are the basis' (and I feel argumentative, for once).

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of "basics".

Comment: @MrLister no, basis (or ``bases``, as Mr. Ashworth astutely pointed out)

Comment: Perhaps explicitly stating together the word ``basis`` makes sense: ``Cooperation, reciprocity and trust together form the **basis** of human prosperity—not selfishness.`` One could argue that this is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

These are sometimes called **[gating](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/whats-the-correct-term-for-gating-criteria)** items or events.

See [this answer from Lawrence](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/301360/216106):

> This is called a gating question. Think of the question as a gate to the rest of the test. If you don't get past the gate, the rest of the test doesn't matter.

See [this answer from me](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/411191/216106):

> And the term I've heard used quite a bit: [gating criteria](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/whats-the-correct-term-for-gating-criteria), which is used in project management to mean a condition required to pass on to the next phase.

See [this question from Thomas Weller](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/94972/48224):

> In project management for software development our bosses have introduced quality gates. The idea is to reach a certain level of quality before the project can continue in the next phase.
>
> Now, the criteria for that are called gating criteria and I wonder whether gating is a good choice. Looking up the Oxford dictionary, there's no such word.

Comment: I like this term. Can think of many instances in which it can be used effectively. Thanks for introducing me to a new word for several contexts.

Comment: The only problem with this word is that it is not likely to be generally understood.

Answer (score 2):

The way to provide leverage in several steps is to use [gears or cogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear).

> Cooperation, reciprocity and trust are the cogs of human prosperity—not selfishness.

Also, another common analogy would be links in a chain but I think you are trying to emphasize the leverage perspective so the above would be preferential in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> Intrinsics

Although it is a plural form, it does sound a little clunky.
If 'the' in the sentence is removed then the use of intrinsic is fine but it loses the OP's requirement for stress on multiples.